# draw a non-rectangular shape using 1) texture image and 2) ColorFilter

Tags: android, graphics, paint, shapedrawable, colorfilter

[image]

This is what i want to draw. It has

- the shape i want (from four [x/y] coordinates)
- the texture i want (from a bmp)
- the color i want (using ColorFilter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatically, this is how i achieved my goal in the end:

```
Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(coord0X, coord0Y);
    path.lineTo(coord1X, coord1Y);
    path.lineTo(coord2X, coord2Y);
    path.lineTo(coord3X, coord3Y);
    path.lineTo(coord0X, coord0Y);

ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, dx, dy));
shapeDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x+dx, y+dy);

shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
Shader fillShader = new BitmapShader(myTextureBitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);          
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(fillShader);
```

I now get a parallelogram drawn with my texture BMP.

To add a ColorFilter:

```
shapeDrawable.setColorFilter(myColorFilter);
```